# UserControl Contents only updates the first time it is shown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am facing an issue with data binding in a custom UserControl.

It is pretty much an error dialog overlay that gets called on a button press if errors are found in the user inputs.

In the control I have 2 objects, an exit button and a string list that contains the errors.

My issue is that the list on the user control is set the first time the dialog visibility is set to true, and then doesn't refresh after that. 
I am calling OnNotifyPropertyChange when I alter the list, but it still seems to make no difference.

My MainContent XAML UserContent Section.

```
<Grid x:Name="Overlay" Panel.ZIndex="1000"  Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowOverlay, Converter={StaticResource booltoVis},FallbackValue=Hidden }" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity=".5"/>
        </Grid.Background>

        <View:UserControl1>

            <View:UserControl1.MainContent>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Error_Message_List, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </View:UserControl1.MainContent>

            <View:UserControl1.DialogExitButton>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseModalDialogClickCommand}" Content="OK">
                </Button>
            </View:UserControl1.DialogExitButton>

        </View:UserControl1>    
</Grid>
```

My User Control binding XAML

```
<Grid Margin="5" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Error in script generation!" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainContent, ElementName=XAMLErrorPopupControl}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding DialogExitButton, ElementName=XAMLErrorPopupControl}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="224,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

My User Control code-behind

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MainContent", 
            typeof(object), 
            typeof(UserControl1),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object),
                   FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public object MainContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(MainContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainContentProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("MainContent"); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogExitButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DialogExitButton", 
            typeof(object), 
            typeof(UserControl1), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object DialogExitButton
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DialogExitButtonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DialogExitButtonProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("DialogExitButton"); }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: can you show your list implementation...is it observabl;e collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** `Error_Message_List` has to be an `ObservableCollection<YourItemType>` to be able to notify UI when items are **added/removed** from the list.

**Second:**  `YourItemType` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify UI  when an item from the list gets **modified**.

Comment: That was it, Error_Message_List was only a List. Stupid mistake, I had used ObservableCollection for all my main window collections... Thanks heaps!